# Call function inside function by v-on:click

Tags: javascript, function, methods, vue.js

How can I able to call function inside function ?

**Template :** *(HTML)*

```
<a v-on:click="hello.world"></a>
```

**JS :** *(as component)*

```
methods: {
    hello: function() {
        return {
            world: function() {
                alert('hello world');
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**This I got warning :**

> [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

This is possible to call `this.hello().world()` by JS **but not in template** *(html)* like `v-on`

**What i am missing ?**

Comment: Use it like this `<a v-on:click="hello().world()">foo</a>`

Comment: Yes !!!!! , Should be the answer @BelminBedak Post it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be used in a bit different way to make it working

```
<a v-on:click="hello().world()">foo</a>
```

http://jsbin.com/lizerazire/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a vue issue.

`this.hello().world()` is not valid because   `world()` is not accessible now. Try adding double brackets `()` at the and of `hello` function:

```
methods: {
  hello: function() {
    return {
        world: function() {
            alert('hello world');
        }
    }();
  }
}
```

And you can now access the inner function like this: `this.hello.world()`;

Answer (score 0):

Just define world as a function either inside methods, globally or in the vue component and call it in a regular fashion.

`<a @click="hello">foo</a>`

```
function world() {
  alert("hello world");
}

<vue component> {
  methods: {
    hello: function() {
        world();
    }
  }
}
```

or this

```
<vue component> {
  methods: {
    hello: function() {
        this.world();
    },
    world: function() {
        alert("Hello world");
    }
  }
}
```